# how to enable Angular ssr with stenciljs

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, stenciljs, hydration

I'm trying to connect Stencil WebComponents to Angular app with enabled Angular universe SSR. I really don't know how I can turn on hydration to make the components work properly, here are server.ts functions:

```
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/angular/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', async (req, res) => {
    // commented original code:
    // res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });

    // what i wanted to add without success:
    const renderedHtml = await hydrate.renderToString(indexHtml);
    res.render(renderedHtml.html, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}
```

I checked other topics && Stencil.js [docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/v2/hydrate-app), but i didn't found example with Angular app with enabled SSR, also the documentation is rly poor

I tried to add hydrate with renderToString in server method

Answer (score 0):

It is quite a while since this question was asked, and most likely not relevant anymore. The [express](https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#app.render) `.render(err, html)` accepts a third argument. This is a callback you can utilize to hydrate your app.

```js
import { renderToString } from '@myPackage/hydrate';

// taken from the server.ts (generated by angular universal during inital setup)
res.render(indexHtml, { req }, (err, html) => {
  renderToString(html).then(({html})=> {
    res.send(html);
  });
});
```

The callback cannot send the rendered view to the client on its own. So you need to send it back to client using `res.send(html)`